# Estimate parameter using MLE method

Tags: maximum-likelihood, circular-statistics

$$L=-2n\log(2 \pi)-n \log I_0(\lambda p)+\sum_{i=1}^{n} [\lambda p\cos(x_i-X_i)]-\sum_{i=1}^{n}log[c-m_1\cos(y_i-BX_i)-m_2\sin(y_i-BX_i)]$$

where $\lambda, X_i, m_1, m_2 , p$ are parameter

i reach to this in MLE method

I need to derive this relation with respect to $B$  to estimate it .

I attempt to derive with respect to $B$ but the step was complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

When you partial derivative with respect to $B$, you can ignore terms that do not involve $B$.

Hence it suffices to focus on

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\log[c-m_1\cos(y_i-BX_i)-m_2\sin(y_i-BX_i)]$$

Now, try to use chain rule to differentiate with respect to $B$.

Edit:

\begin{align}\frac{\partial}{\partial B} m_1\cos(y_i  - BX_i)&=m_1\frac{\partial}{\partial B} \cos(y_i  - BX_i)\\
&=-m_1 \sin(y_i  - BX_i) \frac{\partial}{\partial B} (y_i  - BX_i)\text{, chain rule here}\\
&= -m_1\sin(y_i-BX_i)(-X_i) \\
&=m_1X_i\sin(y_i-BX_i)\end{align}

Edit 2: Note that we have

\begin{align}\frac{\partial}{\partial B} &\log[c-m_1\cos(y_i-BX_i)-m_2\sin(y_i-BX_i)]\\&= \frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial B} \left( -m_1\cos(y_i-BX_i)-m_2\sin(y_i-BX_i)\right)}{c-m_1\cos(y_i-BX_i)-m_2\sin(y_i-BX_i)}\end{align}

Comment: the problem of me how i can sperate of B and $X_i$  . please explian more how i can use chain rule

Comment: I have included an example of how to apply chain rule for the first term. Note that in general, we don't have a closed form formula and have to rely on numerical methods.

Comment: ok , but there exist log .... this is clear for me but i need to estimate B in this relation , i must derive with respect to B and then equal zero ,,,I try but no reslut ,,, is there any idea else

Comment: chain rule stil works in terms of deriving some conditions, in terms of solving it you might need some numerical method.